# PowerShell Compilation to .exe

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a PowerShell script that uses PowerShell 3 to perform REST API calls. The script works as intended in PowerShell 3, however, REST API calls are not supported in PowerShell 2. Unfortunately the users of the script all have PowerShell 2. Is there any way to compile the PowerShell script to an .exe such that the users of the .exe do not require a PowerShell 3 installation? I tried PS2EXE but it did not work when testing on a machine with PowerShell 2. Are there any compilers for PS that have this capability?

Comment: I think all of these 'compilers' work in the same way as `PS2EXE`, in that they just embed the PS code in an exe and extract and run it on the fly, thus requiring PowerShell to be installed on the host system.  I am not aware of any that actually convert the code to stand-alone exes.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [PrimalScript](https://www.sapien.com/software/primalscript) or [PowerShell Studio](https://www.sapien.com/software/powershell_studio) if the users *need* to run the script from the command-line. Both of those tools will output an exe that includes the runtime so the target environment won't have to have PowerShell v3.

If your users *don't* have to run the script from the shell, you could wrap it in a web GUI using [System Frontier](https://systemfrontier.com/solutions/powershell/). Then they could run it from any modern browser without needing a specific PowerShell run-time on their machines.

Comment: I believe both of those suggested however are paid solutions, is that correct?

Comment: All three are. The question didn't specify free, paid or open source. I love free and open source tools like the next person, but many great solutions to answers include paid products too.